# Count the number of distinct subarrays

Tags: java, algorithm, array, dynamic-programming

I want to determine the number of distinct subarrays that can form having at most a given number of odd elements. Two subarrays are distinct if they differ at even one position. The subarray is a contiguous position of an array. Please give some suggestions to improve the time and space complexity.

```
Exp1:
Input: nums = [1, 2, 3, 4], k = 1
Output: 8 
Explanation: [1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4]
```

```
Exp2:
Input: nums = [3, 2, 3, 4], k = 1
Output: 7 
Explanation: [3], [2], [4], [3, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 3, 4]
Note we did not count [3, 2, 3] since it has more than k odd elements.
```

```
Exp3:
Input: nums = [3, 2, 3, 2], k = 1
Output: 5
Explanation: [3], [2], [3, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 2]
[3], [2], [3, 2] - duplicates
[3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3, 2] - more than k odd elements
```

---

```
class result {
       
    static int numberOfSubarrays(int[] numbers, int k) {
        if(k == 0) return 0;
        
        boolean [] IsOdd = new boolean [numbers.length];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            IsOdd[i] = numbers[i] %2 != 0;
        }
        
        HashSet<String> subs = new HashSet<String>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int oddCount = 0;
            
            for(int j = i; j < numbers.length; j++){
                if(IsOdd[j]){
                    oddCount++;
                    if(oddCount > k){ 
                        break;
                    }
                }
                sb.append(numbers[j] + " ");
                subs.add(sb.toString());
            }
        }
        return subs.size();
    }

}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Review, the first thing I see in your code is:

```
class result { ..your code }
```

Instead of `result` you should use `Result` as a classname because as specified in [java_naming_conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) : *Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized*.

The second thing I see in your code is:

```
HashSet<String> subs = new HashSet<String>();
```

Better to declare instead `Set<String> subs = new HashSet<String>();` that guarantees more flexibility in case you want to use another implementation of the`Set` interface.

About performance, briefly you have a `for` loop where you instantiate a new `StringBuilder` object at every iteration like below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   ...other instructions
   sb.append(numbers[j] + " ");
}
```

There is a debated alternative to this scenario corresponding to instantiate one single `StringBuilder` object with a fixed capacity and resetting its length at every iteration of the loop with the [`StringBuilder.setLength`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength-int-) method like below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Arrays.toString(numbers).length());
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
   ...other instructions
   sb.setLength(0);
}
```

For every testcase I set the capacity of the `StringBuilder` object to
the length of the `String` representation of the initial array like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` that is the maximal string length the `StringBuilder` will contain.

*Update after @TorbenPutkonen comment* : better to use `StringBuilder.setLength(0)` at the beginning of the loop to improve readibility of the code, so the reader has a clear vision of the state of the `StringBuilder` at the beginning and not at the end.

Comment: When used in a loop, the preference should be to reset the `StringBuilder` with `setLength(0)` before it's use begins instead of after it has been used. This way the reader does not have to go through all the code to find out what the state of the StringBuilder is at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen - You are completely right, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @dariosicily if I do that, it will mess up the output.

Comment: @wagaga I don't understand in which way it will mess up the output, I substituted the creation of one empty `StringBuilder` at every iteration with the creation of one `StringBuilder` that will be reset at every iteration.